# Why does RAZOR output a capitalized boolean value?

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

```
@{
    bool a = false;
 }    

<script>

var element = '<a href="www.testurl.com" + '?a=' + @(a)';
$('#anyElement').append(element);

</script>
```

The anchor tag will have the href of, www.testurl.com?a=False

In IE11, at least, variable a will be rendered as False instead of false. This causes an ECMAScript error because now the JavaScript/ECMAScript compiler thinks False is an undefined variable.

Why does RAZOR not render this variable in lowercase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Razor just uses the `ToString()`-method of whatever you put there. In case of a `bool`, that will evaluate to `True` or `False`. To circumvent the problem, just lowercase it yourself:

```
@{
    bool a = false;
}    

<script>

var element = '<a href="www.testurl.com" + '?a.ToString().ToLower()=' +   @(a)';
$('#anyElement').append(element);

</script>
```

Comment: I hate that this happens, but it works.